# Python Split a hex character - bitshift

Tags: python, split, hex, padding

Here is my code:

```
ROSF = 30e3;
MCLK = 16e6;
SFC = (ROSF/(MCLK/4))*(2**27);
SFC = int(SFC);
SFC = hex(SFC);
print SFC;
```

I get `0xf5c28`, but I wanna get `0x0f5c28`.

After that, I'd like to have 3 variables with 2 characters inside. I'd like to split my hex number in 3 pieces to get the following variables:

```
set1 = 0x0f
set2 = 0x5c
set3 = 0x28
```

Comment: `0x%06s"%hex(SFC)[2:]` is a way you could do that i guess ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I think the OP looks for a more generic way that adds a leading zero in case the number of digits is odd.

Comment: @DonPepper: should the `set` variables be strings, or integers?

Comment: in that case `0x%0*s"%(len(hex(SFC))-(2-len(hex(SFC))%2),  hex(SFC)[2:])`

Comment: You could probably add `.zfill(6)` on the end of your string.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: they should be hex strings

Comment: Use a [*format string*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: @JoranBeasley `0x%0*s"%(len(hex(SFC))-(2-len(hex(SFC))%2), hex(SFC)[2:])` How should i use it?

Comment: i used `test3 = "{0:#0{1}x}".format(SFC,8);`  how can i split it into 3 variables? to get:  

`set1 = 0x0f
set2 = 0x5c
set3 = 0x28 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
ROSF = 30e3
MCLK = 16e6
SFC = int((ROSF/(MCLK/4))*(2**27))
register1 = ((SFC >> 16) & 0x00FF)
register2 = ((SFC >> 8) & 0x00FF)
register3 = (SFC  & 0x00FF)
print(hex(register1))
print(hex(register2))
print(hex(register3))
```

Sorry for my bad question. But this is what i wanted.